# How can I change label colour using one timer in (VB 6.0)

Tags: timer, vb6

I try to use one timer to change label colour twice ..

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
Timer1.Interval = Timer1.Interval + 1000
If (Timer1.Interval = 1000) Then
    Label1.ForeColor = vbRed
End If
If (Timer1.Interval = 2000) Then
    Label1.ForeColor = vbBlue
End If
```

Please Help me with this and thank you ^_^

Comment: So, are you 1) assigning an initial value to the timer's interval, 2) starting the timer?

Comment: If it misses the micro second that it is going to change on, you will miss it. How about doing >= 1000 and < 2000 for red, and >= 2000 from blue.

Comment: thank you so much Chuck i do like you sad and it's work ...

Comment: thank you  David T. Macknet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank for any one answer me for my question David T. Macknet & chuck ... chuck told me to do this

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
Timer1.Interval = Timer1.Interval + 1000
If (Timer1.Interval >= 1000) Then
    Label1.ForeColor = vbRed
End If
If (Timer1.Interval <= 2000) Then
    Label1.ForeColor = vbBlue
End If
```

and it's work and change colour twice with one timer ...
thank you chuck and for every one in this website ^_^

Comment: Let me ask: What happens after, lets say, about ... 6 minutes? I think you will run into a problem.